# Delimiter for rowkey as composite key in hbase

Tags: hbase, sqoop

By default if we use composite key as rowkey in hbase the delimiter is '_'(underscore). Can we use otherthan underscore as delimiter. We are using sqoop to import the data.

Ex:

Default : `id_deptcode_branchcode`

Custom: Is it possible to use some other delimiter(except underscore) in rowkey using sqoop

```
id|deptcode|branchcode
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hbase/ToStringPutTransformer.java#L70), no, you can't:

```
/**
* Used as connecting char for storing composite-key values to form.
* composite row-key on hbase
*/
public static final String DELIMITER_HBASE = "_";
```

Comment: Yes, cant we override this delimiter with any hbase configuration? In composite key value we are having character "_"  this causing a problem for us in rowkey.

Comment: No. But you can rewrite rowkeys with MapReduce or Spark job if that is option for you.